# Applescript detect enabled edit box

Tags: applescript

My script gets some text from AppA and pastes it into a text edit on AppB. When AppB is started (by the script) the text edit is disabled, becoming enabled when the user performs an action. That action needs to stay manual.

The script executes before the user has time to anything, an error. My thought was to check if the edit is enabled, but that gives this error. "Can't get window of AppB of <> "AppB" of application "System Events". It only throws the error once.

How can I avoid the error? Would a try block to just eat the error be better?

```
on idle
 tell application "System Events" to set AppAIsOpen to (application process "AppA" exists)
if (AppAIsOpen) then
  set AppAWasOpen to true
  tell application "AppA"
    set hdg to TxRprt
    set beam to hdg as string
  end tell
  if ((count beam) < 3) then set beam to text -3 thru -1 of ("000" & beam)
    if (beam is not previousText) then
      tell application "AppB" to launch
        tell application "System Events"
          tell application process "AppB"
        if text field 1 of window "AppB" is enabled then  -- error here
          set value of text field 1 of window "AppB" to beam  --or here
        end if
      end tell
    end tell
    set previousText to beam
      end if
    return checkInterval
else if (AppAgWasOpen) then
  quit
      return 1
end if
```

end idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I enter a repeat loop and check for a text field (or any interface element) to become available before trying to do anything with it. Something like this would work and should eliminate your errors.

Notice I also add a time-check to this process so that I do not get stuck in the repeat loop. In this case I wait 5 seconds max for the text field to become available.

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- wait for the text field to become available
    set startTime to current date
    repeat until exists (text field 1 of window "AppB" of application process "AppB")
        if (current date) - startTime is greater than 5 then
            error "Could not find text field 1 of window AppB of application process AppB"
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 0.2
    end repeat

    tell application process "AppB"
        if text field 1 of window "AppB" is enabled then -- error here
            set value of text field 1 of window "AppB" to beam --or here
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```